# Set items to QML ListModel dynamicaly with PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have a QML that represent schedule, that get values from database, so I need insert values to `ListModel` from my python code. QML looks like that:

```
function append(newElement) {
    scheduleList.model.append(newElement)
}

ListView {
    id: scheduleList
    model: scheduleModel
    delegate: scheduleItem

    section.property: "day"
    section.delegate: sectionDelegate
}

Component {
    id: scheduleItem
    Rectangle {
        Row {
            spacing: 15
            Text {
                text: lesson
            }
            Text {
                text: subject
            }
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: sectionDelegate
    Rectangle {
        id: root
        Text {
            id: label
            text: section
        }
    }
}
```

And I a function, that should insert values to QML ListModel:

```
class ScheduleView(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._presenter = SchedulePresenter(self)
        self._widget = QQuickWidget(parent)
        self._widget.rootContext().setContextProperty('scheduleView', self)
        self._widget.rootContext().setContextProperty('groupsModel', self)
        self._widget.setSource(QUrl('modules/schedule/Form.qml'))

def reprSchedules(self):
    values = [{"lesson": "1", "subject": "PE", "day": "Monday"},
              {"lesson": "2", "subject": "PE", "day": "Monday"},
              {"lesson": "3", "subject": "PE", "day": "Monday"}]
    #model = self._widget.rootObject().findChild(QObject, "scheduleModel")
```

I have no ideas how to do that. Could you help me, please? I'm using Python2.7, PyQt5.9, QtQuick2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you can invoke the append function that you have implemented in the .qml through `QMetaObject.invokeMethod()` as shown below:

**main.py**

```
counter = 0

def onTimeout(obj):
    global counter
    value = {"lesson": str(counter), "subject": "PE", "day": QDate.longDayName(1 + counter % 7)}
    QMetaObject.invokeMethod(obj, "append", Q_ARG(QVariant, value))
    counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QQuickWidget()
    w.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: onTimeout(w.rootObject()))
    timer.start(1000)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    function append(newElement) {
        scheduleModel.append(newElement)
    }
    ListModel {
        id: scheduleModel
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: scheduleList
        model: scheduleModel
        delegate: scheduleItem

        section.property: "day"
        section.delegate: sectionDelegate
    }


    Component {
        id: scheduleItem
            Row {
                spacing: 15
                Text {
                    text: lesson
                }
                Text {
                    text: subject
                }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: sectionDelegate
            Text {
                id: label
                text: section
            }
    }
}
```

The complete example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46721954)

Comment: [Updated link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46721954)